# Json array contains an image url. How do I display that image?

Tags: php, html, json

I have a decoded set of json response data so when I do this:

```
$response = json_decode($data);

echo $response[img_url];
```

And open the .php file in a browser I get the link. How do I take the next step so that I can display an image with that file instead of the link?

Searches for trying to take json array data and displaying it in html points me to how to take list items and put them in html tables. If that is the extent of what I can do with arrays and html, do I need another step between going from array to html? or do I need to not put the $response into an array and put it into something else?

Answer (score 0):

Trying echoing the URL in an image tag:

```
echo '<img src="'.$response['img_url'].'" />';
```

Also, let me take this opportunity to highlight one of the benefits of single quotes: You don't have to escape double-quoted HTML attribute values!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path in `$response['image_url']` you can just use the html img tag like this:

```
echo '<img src="'..$response['image_url']'" />';
```

This would display the actual image and not the url.